# Can anyone please tell me the location of energy?

Tags: electrostatics, energy, electric-fields, charge, capacitance

the formula $Q^2/2C$ gives the energy for a concentric spherical capacitor, where $C=$capacitance of the capacitor and $Q=$charge but i cannot understand where the energy is situated. is it in the electric field in the space between the two capacitors?

Comment: Note to anyone encountering this in the review, as I did:  the original version of the question was quite homework-like, but this version (I think) should stay open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign a quantity $\frac12 \epsilon_0 E^2 \Delta V$ of energy to each small volume, $\Delta V$, of space between the concentric 'plates' you do get a total energy of $\frac{Q^2}{2C}$. To show this is a good exercise if you haven't done it! I think most of us would say that the energy resides in the space (or in the field), but, as gandalf16 explains, strictly this is unjustified – a sort of category mistake.

Comment: Perhaps, though, the distinction verges on the philosophical. Compare with: "Where does consciousness (or the mind) reside?"

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think energy needs to have a physical location ? Energy is an attribute of a system as a whole, which depends on the configuration of the system. You can assign an energy value to each point in the configuration space of a system (as long as the forces involved are conservative forces) but this energy value does not necessarily have a physical location.

Comment: Wouldn't it make a difference as far as gravitational effects are concerned, though?  The curvature of spacetime depends not just on the total amount of mass-energy present but also on its distribution in space.  In that context, it *does* "need to have a physical location."

Comment: Poynting's theorem tells us that the energy of electromagnetic fields is not only globally conserved but in fact locally conserved. So we can assign a location to this energy.